# Avoiding timeout while building HTTP response in Camel REST DSL

Tags: http, apache-camel

I'm using Camel's REST DSL for handling a number of REST responses.
The typical pattern is something like this:

```
Message msg = exchange.getIn();
Thing athing = process();
msg.setBody(athing);
message.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, 200);
```

For one of these operations the process() method can take several minutes which results in the client or an intermediate proxy timing out (e.g. 504 errors) because no response is received in a given time. In this case I cannot easily stream the 'athing' object - I must wait for it to be completely created before I can use it.

Is there a simple way to keep the response alive without having to resort to things like redirects? I just need to send something every few seconds saying I'm still working on it so that the connection is retained.

Comment: You should look at setting a response timeout at the client end. This should not be the responsibility of the service.

Comment: That won't work. The timeout (504) is coming from the proxy server that sits between the client and the server.